# Auto Refresh div using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a problem using auto refresh div tag using mvc pattern. Please help me... here is my code...
included file name with one1.php:

```
 <?php 
    $textnameObj = new textname();
    $textname = $textnameObj->getCont('status','1');
    echo $textname['details'];
    ?>
```

calling that included file name in index.php:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      setInterval("$('#autoref').load('includes/one1.php');", 10000);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="autoref">
   <?php include('includes/one1.php'); ?>
</div>
</body></html>
```

While Second time it refresh I got this error...
Fatal error: Class 'textname' not found in includes/one1.php on line 2

Comment: include textname class in one1.php

Answer (score 1):

In `index.php` you have included `textname` class file. But if you are calling `includes/one1.php` independently, the class `textname` is not defined.

In `includes/one1.php`, you have to [include_once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php) a file, where `textname` class is defined.